# One way hash functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use One way hash functions in T-SQL (Microsoft SQL) for Hash data ?

Comment: Hash functions are always one-way by definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight from the manual, with examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

Answer (score 2):

From SQL Server 2005 and on, [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) is a built in function which can deal with MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA and SHA1. Example:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', 'foo');
```

Note that the input should be a varchar, nvarchar or a varbinary. [This blogpost](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/28/Comparing-SQL-Server-HASHBYTES-function-and-.Net-hashing.aspx) highlights some of the caveeats when using HASHBYTES with columns such as char/nchar.